# Is there something similar to perror?

Tags: zig

I've been test running zig recently, and have been able to pick up most of it by simply reading the standard library. However, I can't find anything similar to how we do `perror/strerror` in C. Is there a way to get a string representation for operating system errors (`errno`) in zig?

To be clear, I'm looking for a zig way to do this:

```c
const char* path = "filethatdoesntexist.txt";
FILE* f = fopen(path,"rb");
if (!f) {
    perror(path);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing is [`@errorName`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#errorName) for Zig errors, but it only returns a simple string representation of the error. E.g.

```
std.debug.assert(std.mem.eql(u8, @errorName(error.FileNotFound), "FileNotFound"))
```

If you're linking libc and using an API that returns `errno`, then you have the option of using `perror` and `strerror` directly.

Comment: This works for me.  I think using `@errorName` is ideal here.  Using raw system calls (on Linux) can return `-errno`, but wouldn't set libc's global `errno` so this is probably most flexible. Thank you!